# Disable Android soft keyboard in ASP.NET

Tags: html

I have a web app build in ASP.NET for our return goods.  The app works well but is about to much more complicated on the input side.  To ease this burden I want to use a Bluetooth barcode scanner and an android tablet for input.  The app looks great when the onscreen keyboard is not visible.  The user needs to enter a quantity, change focus to the barcode input field and scan.  Instead of using the onscreen kb I want to build a key pad on the app for the user and not have the onscreen kb pop up on when the qty or barcode fields get focus.

Can this be done in html, javascript or C#?